# how to avoid many #ifdef for logging statements

Tags: c++, c, logging

In our application, we created our own **logging system**. There are several **different log types**, debug, error, warning, communication, performance and ..., in this logging system. There are lots of **#ifdef** and **#endif** to disable a specific log type. These **#ifdef** and **#endif** make the code hard to read.

We are thinking remove these **#ifdef** and **#endif** and have a check before the message write to the file. That means there are lots of "**useless**" calls to the logging system. These calls will not result in any writing activity.

Is there a **better** way to turn on/off a log type, without these **#ifdef** and **#endif** ***`AND`*** these "**useless**" calls?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? Do you just mean 1 ifdef per logging type, or something else? Maybe some code showing the ifdefs would help...

Comment: Can't you contain all the ifdefs in one place with something like `#ifdef ENABLE_WARN \n #define WARN(x) printf(x) \n #else \n #define WARN(x) \n #endif`?

Comment: @cluracan Not 100% sure, but my guess is that the OP is trying to avoid having a ton of `#ifdef DEBUG ... #endif` everywhere

Comment: You could make the optimizer omit those useless calls using a const global log level and separate functions  for each type (i.e. if(log_lvl < 3) ect)

Comment: @DennisMeng You mean he's putting the ifdefs inside the code?! In that case just do an ifdef once in a header file that defines a "log_error/warning/communication" macros that either do nothing or log depending on the loglevel?

Answer (score 7):

What about the following:

```
// comment out if not needed
#define ENABLE_LOG

#ifdef ENABLE_LOG
#  define LOG(x) x
#else
#  define LOG(x) (void) 0 
#endif
```

Later you could just call:

```
LOG(mylogger.call());
```

Updated the `#else` part as Dietrich Epp suggested.

Comment: I recommend `define LOG(x) (void) 0` for the `else` branch, since it won't generate compiler warnings for extra semicolons.

Comment: why we need the #else part?

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA otherwise if you didn't enable logging, the call to `LOG(mylogger.call());` would return an error that `LOG` is undefined

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the `#define` solution which works very well, I'd like to present an alternative using templates

```
template<bool B>
void log(std::string message){}

template<>
void log<true>(std::string message){log_internal(message);}

#define DEBUG true
#define COMMUNICATION false

...

log<DEBUG>("this message will be logged");
log<COMMUNICATION>("this message won't");
```

The `#define` solution really is great for most cases, but there are some reasons to use this solution:

- You may need scoping - i.e. not having your `log` devices dirty the global namespace. This solution can be put in a `namespace` where the `#define` one can't.
- You may need stricter control on what can and can't be done. The `LOG(x)` define has the problem that anything can be put in the `x` - and if the logging is turned off you won't see a problem.

To clarivy - your code might compile and work with

```
LOG(std::cout << "Here!" << endl);
```

because this specific log is turned off. But one day 2 years from now someone will turn on the logging and get `endl undefined` errors all over the place. Or worse - he may find that turning on logging suddenly requires linking to a library long gone (because that logging specifically called a function defined in this library), or uses a function that has long-since changed interface (or even was removed completely! True story :( )

**Edit**

I was asked to add this to the answer:

It may seem like there's a function call overhead in cases where you don't log (the empty function). This isn't the case as the compiler optimizes it out. If you want to be sure of this - add an `inline` directive to the functions.

Also, you might want to change it from an `std::string` to a `const char *` just to make sure no string constructor is called - but that too should be optimized out automatically by the compiler.

Anyway, like I said this isn't intrinsically better than the `#define` solution. I actually still use the `#define` in my projects - but there are some specific instances where this template solution is preferable.

Comment: Won't this still make a call to the log function when it is turned off? Even though the actual function does nothing. Where as the #define method the LOG lines will be as if nothing was ever there when it gets compiled in the off state.

Comment: @OnlyJoe No, it won't. The compiler sees it's an empty function so it does nothing. If you really want you can add `inline` directive to make sure thought.

Comment: @cluracan can you add that inline directive to your answer?